# Get-AzureAdDevice filtering by Device ID

Tags: azure, powershell, intune

I have a list of Azure DeviceIDs and want to delete them with the Powershell command Remove-AzureADDevice, but i can only delete them by the ObjectID of a device.
so my question now is where i get the matching objectIDs to the DeviceIDs?
I'm just getting this Error-Message

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\powershell\restazure.csv"

foreach($item in $csv){
    $removeThisDevices = Get-AzureAdDevice -Filter "deviceId eq $item.ID"
    }
```

> Message: Syntax error: character '{' is not valid at position 13 in
> 'deviceId eq @{ID=445925f3-c35b-40af-b5d4-1f71dee08a39}.ID'.

Comment: The interpolation is failing in the string.  Replace `$item.ID` with `$($item.ID)` and see if that helps.

Comment: `Get-AzureAdDevice -Filter "deviceId eq '$($item.ID)'"` should work

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me crazy yesterday.  If you look at the error it will complain about the type mismatch.  DeviceID is a GUID.

I had no luck using a GUID typed variable:

```
$guid = [GUID]$deviceId
Get-AzureAdDevice -Filter "deviceId eq $($guid)"
```

This works:

```
#In my case it was an AD object
$deviceId = $adcomp.objectGuid
Get-AzureAdDevice -Filter "deviceId eq guid'$($deviceID)'" #<--yes, you need the single quotes.
```

Thank klikr on GitHub for posting the solution and link to help file which seems to spell out quite a few things: https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues/216#issuecomment-633943632

Help file: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.0.52/Content/it%5CMicrosoft.Open.AzureAD16.Graph.PowerShell.dll-Help.xml

Unlike klikr :-P, I'll be reading some OData documentation this weekend so I can better understand all this.  I'm finding myself writing more automation which requires Azure err Entra data, so it'd be nice if I just knew and didn't have to search and play around to figure certain things out.  Great that they have casting functionality though.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$alldevices = Get-AzureADDevice -All:$true

$ids = "aea06b1b-5413-49fb-9529-372cabb8bfa0",
"642734b1-d804-4043-94e6-ce6508b5ca5b",
"afd5bf18-752b-4b54-84f5-56426dd9b716",
"5d0b7ae6-c600-41e5-90d8-4bac58f21463",
"4f2f91e0-0b06-45c4-a04c-067620c81359",
"cab6a732-dc97-4209-bc05-87353d6dbeab",
"1e8b4deb-e7f1-4e0c-be7d-0a2219fffeb2"

$alldevices | ? {$_.DeviceId -in $ids}
ObjectId                             DeviceId                             DisplayName
--------                             --------                             -----------
0af944f0-bdf5-48c8-828d-c966b7b4f48c 5d0b7ae6-c600-41e5-90d8-4bac58f21463 H170HmNP0
115f4236-bb15-4400-8d2a-25788216476b afd5bf18-752b-4b54-84f5-56426dd9b716 Ø967BEN
3fc6c791-f42e-4d1e-a5b5-662d2904e41a 642734b1-d804-4043-94e6-ce6508b5ca5b Ø967
541afa98-0664-4346-861a-456514f7f90c 4f2f91e0-0b06-45c4-a04c-067620c81359 Ø967BN
8d01df67-856d-4c19-8252-71dbe4b10263 aea06b1b-5413-49fb-9529-372cabb8bfa0 Ø967Bwhuw
d5fbf819-4879-4c8d-97c8-8379d56316ff 1e8b4deb-e7f1-4e0c-be7d-0a2219fffeb2 Ø967BIsCCk
d6ce3aef-4d12-4584-907c-6ded1630f6ec cab6a732-dc97-4209-bc05-87353d6dbeab Ø967BWbOm
f650da66-e978-42f9-9206-ad32be413769 435ae308-601f-4784-aff8-6f3ca2adc827 Ø967BrBg
```